# How to achieve Google style of getting search results?

Tags: php, url

I typed this in Google:

```
<span class=""></span>
```

And on my URL, it returned:

```
q=<span+class%3D""><%2Fspan>&btnK=
```

It appears that it converted spaces, equals (=) sign, and backslashes into something.

Additionally, it didn't show anything different on the search box.
Is this secure? If so, how do I achieve this?

Thank you people!

Comment: This is basic URL encoding, and doesn't have anything to do with preventing XSS attacks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://www.php.net/urlencode

```
string urlencode ( string $str )
```

It depends on what you're trying to do, but urlencode will do something similar to google's search box.

Comment: I get it. So with it, I can possibly avoid XSS?

Comment: @witherwind No, you can't.  It's for an entirely different purpose.  URL encoding simply keeps reserved characters from being ambiguous in the querystring.

Comment: What @Brad said, XSS is an entirely separate, and much more complicated issue

Comment: Sorry I'm new to this kind of stuff. Sure I can code, but this somehow is in a whole new level for me. What's it's purpose then?

Comment: @witherwind See my prior comment:  URL encoding simply keeps reserved characters from being ambiguous in the querystring.